# Dynamic Reports in Splunk

Tags: reporting, splunk

I want to pass splunk query as token.

I have tried it.But the passed query stops at the first equal symbol.For eg if splunk query is index=cq*.Then it is passed only till index.Things from first equal symbol are not considered.Morever any query can contain multiple = signs.

Comment: Here I have used passing splunk query as token a way of getting dynamic reports.Any other way except using depends is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to URL-encode the query before passing it.

Comment: If i encode how do i decode the token in other dashboard where i am using the token

Comment: I've never had to worry about that.  It's automatic.

Comment: No it is not for me,'+' replaces each space in my splunk query after encoding.so if i directly pass the encoded query,the dashboard receiving the encoded query as token,shows error message it could n't parse the query.Can you post some example of query before encoding and after encoding so that I can reach the solution

Comment: It would seem you have a different problem from what I've encountered myself.  If you post your dashboard code, especially the part within <drilldown> tags, I'll try to see what can be improved.